# plugin giving error but not visible in plugins Plugin "Android WiFi ADB" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: android-studio

Get error every time i start my android studio, i try to un-install them but they are not visible in installed-plugins how do i remove them. These plugins unsupported in the current version of android studio one day i update my android studio and then i failed to remove them and get error.

```
Plugin Error
                Plugin "Android WiFi ADB" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).
                Plugin "ADB WiFi Connect" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove "Android WiFi ADB"、"ADB WiFi Connect"

Windows: C:\Users\PCUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio*\Plugins

MacOS:  ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio*/plugins

linux: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio*/plugins or ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/
```